# Error: variables ‘hashtags’, ‘digits’ were specified with different types from the fit

Tags: r, machine-learning

New to R, So I got a homework task to predict the spam/non-spam data, I have been provided with test data and training data, both of them have labelled the same, I've trained the last label which is spam/non-spam from the training data set but when I try to predict the test, I get "Error: variables ‘hashtags’, ‘digits’ were specified with different types from the fit".. what should I use to specify weather the dataset is spam or not

```
colnames(testing_data2) <- c(
"age",
"followers",
"following",
"userfav",
"list",
"tweets",
"retweets",
"tweetfav",
"hashtags",
"usermentions",
"urls",
"chars",
"digits",
"classification"            
)
```

classification is the spam/non-spam

```
colnames(training_data) <- c(
"age",
"followers",
"following",
"userfav",
"list",
"tweets",
"retweets",
"tweetfav",
"hashtags",
"usermentions",
"urls",
"chars",
"digits",
"classification"
)


rf_fit <- train(as.factor(classification) ~ .,
            data = training_data,
            method = "ranger")
rf_fit


testing_data2_rf_pred <- predict(rf_fit, testing_data2)  # error here
```

Comment: Perhaps you could prepare the data outside of formula and try using "clean" names, e.g. ` classification ~ .`? Make sure types match for `testing_data2` and `training_data`.

Comment: in test2, digits and hashtags are Factor w/ 14 levels "0","1","11","12",..: 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 while training is int, how do I change test2 to int?

Comment: You could try `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.